# How do I delete an item(id) from an array using click?

Tags: angular, delete-row

I iam using angular 8 and i'm beginner so i need a help I want to delete an item from array using (click)="deleteEmployee(el.id)" im trying to use splice but i have an error their :

this is Component.ts code :

```
  employee: Employe;
  id: number;

  _employesArray:Employe[]=[];
  headElements = ['ID', 'Nom', 'Prenom', 'Email', 'Telephone', 'CompteStatut'];



  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http:HttpClient, private employeservice:EmployeService, private router: Router) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employee = new Employe();

    this.id =this.route.snapshot.params['id'];


    this.employeservice.getEmployee(this.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.employee = data;
      }, error => console.log(error));
    this.reloadData();
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.employeservice.getEmp().subscribe(
      data=>{
        this._employesArray=data;


      },
      err=>{
        console.log("An error has occured")
      }
    );

  }

  deleteEmployee(id: any) {
    this.employeservice.deleteEmployee(this.id)
      .subscribe(data =>{
      this._employesArray.splice(this._employesArray.indexOf(this.id), 1);
      this.reloadData();
      },

       error => console.log(error));

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few this to clear out here. I see you forwarding the `ID` to a `API` call here. 
Why not show the returned result of the API call straight away in the `Angular` app by removing the object from the API or DB straight away?

If you want to remove a specific object in a your arrray you need to iterate it over.

**Try the below snippet:**

`this._employesArray= this._employesArray.filter(employee=> employee.id === this.id);`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the .filter builtin method to remove an item from an array.

```
 deleteEmployee(id: any) {
    this.employeservice.deleteEmployee(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          // this will return a new array of employees after removing the employee given by the id
          this._employesArray = this._employeeArray.filter(employee => employee.id !== id);
        },
        error => console.log(error));
  }
```